# Change how the compiler parses the string

Tags: java, c#, string

In c#, @ sign is used before string literals to change how the compiler parses the string.
Is there a counterpart of this in java? Using concatenation confuses me sometimes.

Comment: You can use `Pattern.quote` and Java will quote everything for you.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Would be better to add it as an answer? :\

Comment: i want something like this.

`String str = "I am 
            a kid ";`
after a is next line
and java like c# by using @ will still accept that code.

Comment: oh man, java still doesn't have this feature. but anyways, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Strings cannot be on multiple lines in java. Your editor may automatically wrap them, but the string itself cannot be on multiple lines - that is, don't hit enter in the middle of a string literal.

If you want your string to contain a new line, use \n
ex

```
System.out.println("Line 1\nLine 2");
```

results in

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Comment: thanks for the advice dude. but what i wanted in my program is that i don't want any + signs because sometimes it confuses me and i hit enter in the middle of the string literal.

Comment: ah. Java can't really deal with that without concatenating them, like you said.

Comment: Fortunately, the compiler will catch it for you.